# Skip a few columns in a row and then write

Tags: php, html

I loop through the resultset and write in an HTML table. But I want skip a few columns in each row depending upon a counter. ie, if `counter == 1` then write in the first column of the row, if `counter == 5` then write in the 5th row etc. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you accessing the database? I'd recommend posting the code you have so far.

Comment: do the cells you want to skip have dynamic content? you can start your loop right after these cells. for better help, post a sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert an empty column before your column:

```
<tr>
 <td></td><td></td><td>3rd column</td>
</tr>
```

alternatively, use one column with colspan:

```
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"></td><td>3rd column</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
    $html .= '<td></td>';
}
$html .= '<td>' . $whatYouWantToWrite . '</td>';
```

Comment: I tried that  $html .= '<td></td>'; will display an empty cell. But for me that cell may already be written so I don't want to overwrite it. I just want to jump to the 5th($counter) cell and write there.

Comment: You can "jump" to a cell and re-edit anything you want if you keep the entire table in a multidimensional array, which is the preferable way of doing things anyway...